# Java - Choosing the right collection

Tags: java, collections, scjp, ocpjp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rule of thumb for choosing an implementation of a Java Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442/rule-of-thumb-for-choosing-an-implementation-of-a-java-collection)

I am looking for a 'Summary' list of all the Java collections detailing the pros and cons of each. I am particularly interested in things like

- Which provide faster iteration
- Which provide faster search
- Which provide slower iteration
- Which provide faster insertion or removal

I have seen some sites by searching on Google but i am looking for just a summary preferable in table format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/), particularly the section on [implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html), which includes (in subsections) a discussion of performance characteristics for the various predefined classes. The collections framework is so large, I think, that it would be difficult to summarize everything in a single table.