# ruby data structure implementations corresponding to java collections

Tags: java, ruby, data-structures

I am coming form a java world and usually think about a collection interface (set, list, map) that is required and depending on different use case select which concrete implementation to use, something like [this reference of Java Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442/rule-of-thumb-for-choosing-an-implementation-of-a-java-collection)

I am wondering if there is a good summary of analogous ruby data strucutres corresponding to those in java that is available ?

If not can someone provide the favourite implementations people use for:

1. listed here in the table in middle of page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/collections/overview.html

   2. some other ones like say 
      queues: blocking, delayed, linked-blocking queue, circular etc
      trie
      trees
      etc

Better if most are from ruby standard library, otherwise popular gems are fine as well.

My intention is to have a place to refer when selecting good data structure implementations in ruby world

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just browse the classes offered in the [Ruby core](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/) & [standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/)? There's not too many that it'd take a long time to go through. Reading docs may be dry, but it certainly is useful.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look. I was looking for a parallel table with 2 columns java DS, Corresponding Ruby DS . Especially useful when I am looking for a linkedHashMap vs concurrentHashMap, vs sortedMap etc and I dont have to go through a lot of searching and browsing for each of them. It just sounded like a common use case for many so thought may be something like that is already there on the web.

Answer (score 1):

ruby has [set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html)s with along with their [sorted counterpart](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/SortedSet.html). The [array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/array/rdoc/index.html) class handles your list equivalencies from Java, and there is a [hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/hash/rdoc/index.html) class to function like maps. Anything else? Leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks hd1. Is there a tree based implementation of hash (ordered traversal ?)

Comment: Thanks hd1. Is there a tree based implementation of hash (ordered traversal ?) .LinkedHashSet like implementation . The queue implementations I mentioned in the question . Also there are bunch of other ones that guarantee thread safety like ConcurrentHashMap. There are lot more mentioned here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/collections/reference.html.

Comment: The built-in hash is thread-safe, unless you're talking about jruby